# Why does this A-frame code work in Glitch.com but not on my website?

Tags: aframe

Cannot figure out why the A-frame code is working on my glitch.com [here](https://treasure-fourth-cymbal.glitch.me) site but not my website [here](https://cowboyshugging.com/room2). It is the same exact code copied and pasted. The thumbnails all show black on my website and when you click a thumbnail to send you to a different 360 image it flashes then goes black. Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>360&deg; Image Gallery</title>
    <meta name="description" content="360&deg; Image Gallery - A-Frame">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-event-set-component@5/dist/aframe-event-set-component.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-layout-component@5.3.0/dist/aframe-layout-component.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-template-component@3.2.1/dist/aframe-template-component.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-proxy-event-component@2.1.0/dist/aframe-proxy-event-component.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Image link template to be reused. -->
    <script id="link" type="text/html">
      <a-entity class="link"
        geometry="primitive: plane; height: 1; width: 1"
        material="shader: flat; src: ${thumb}"
        event-set__mouseenter="scale: 1.2 1.2 1"
        event-set__mouseleave="scale: 1 1 1"
        event-set__click="_target: #image-360; _delay: 300; material.src: ${src}"
        proxy-event="event: click; to: #image-360; as: fade"
        sound="on: click; src: #click-sound"></a-entity>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-assets>
        <img id="city" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://i.imgur.com/xeNv6sS.jpg">
        <img id="city-thumb" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://i.imgur.com/ibAztjF.gif">
        <img id="cubes-thumb" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.aframe.io/360-image-gallery-boilerplate/img/thumb-cubes.jpg">
        <img id="sechelt-thumb" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.aframe.io/360-image-gallery-boilerplate/img/thumb-sechelt.jpg">
        <audio id="click-sound" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.aframe.io/360-image-gallery-boilerplate/audio/click.ogg"></audio>
        <img id="cubes" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://i.imgur.com/jWWrLUz.jpg">
        <img id="sechelt" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.aframe.io/360-image-gallery-boilerplate/img/sechelt.jpg">

      </a-assets>

      <!-- 360-degree image. -->
      <a-sky id="image-360" radius="10" src="#city"
             animation__fade="property: components.material.material.color; type: color; from: #FFF; to: #000; dur: 300; startEvents: fade"
             animation__fadeback="property: components.material.material.color; type: color; from: #000; to: #FFF; dur: 300; startEvents: animationcomplete__fade"></a-sky>

      <!-- Image links. -->
      <a-entity id="links" layout="type: line; margin: 1.5" position="0 -1 -4">
        <a-entity template="src: #link" data-src="#cubes" data-thumb="#cubes-thumb"></a-entity>
        <a-entity template="src: #link" data-src="#city" data-thumb="#city-thumb"></a-entity>
        <a-entity template="src: #link" data-src="#sechelt" data-thumb="#sechelt-thumb"></a-entity>
      </a-entity>

      <!-- Camera + cursor. -->
      <a-entity camera look-controls>
        <a-cursor
          id="cursor"
          animation__click="property: scale; startEvents: click; from: 0.1 0.1 0.1; to: 1 1 1; dur: 150"
          animation__fusing="property: fusing; startEvents: fusing; from: 1 1 1; to: 0.1 0.1 0.1; dur: 1500"
          event-set__mouseenter="_event: mouseenter; color: springgreen"
          event-set__mouseleave="_event: mouseleave; color: black"
          raycaster="objects: .link"></a-cursor>
      </a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "the A-frame code"? Which code specifically would that be? Please post the actual code and not just links to website(s) using it.

Comment: Sorry. It's updated